# How to separate two geom_bar styles when using second y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with `ggplot` to build a bar plot to compare two measures. My dataframe is composed of dates and two numeric variables. It is `DF` and I will include `dput()` version in the final part of this post. I have two measures, `x` and `y` but they differ totally in scale. So, I used next code to design a bar chart:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x=date)) +
  geom_bar( aes(y=x), stat="identity", position=position_dodge(),
            fill='blue', color="black", alpha=.6) + 
  geom_bar( aes(y=y/0.1), stat="identity", position=position_dodge(),
            fill='red', color="black", alpha=.6) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "x",sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*0.1, name="y"))
```

The code works well but the output does not allow making difference between `x` and `y`:
[image]

As you can see, both bars overlap and it is not possible to differentiate `x` and `y`. I would like to know if there is any option available in `ggplot2` to reach something like this but keeping the two axes:
[image]

Where the values in the bars can be seen separated for each day. I need to keep the second axis to make difference between both scales. The `dput()` version of `DF` is:

```
DF <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18342, 18343, 18344, 18345, 
18346, 18347, 18348, 18349, 18350, 18351, 18352, 18353, 18354, 
18355, 18356, 18357, 18358, 18359, 18360, 18361, 18362, 18363, 
18364, 18365, 18366, 18367, 18368, 18369, 18370, 18371, 18372, 
18373, 18374, 18375, 18376, 18376, 18377, 18378, 18379, 18380, 
18381, 18382, 18383, 18384, 18385, 18386, 18387, 18335, 18336, 
18329, 18330, 18331, 18332, 18333, 18334, 18319, 18320, 18321, 
18337, 18338, 18339, 18340, 18341, 18322, 18323, 18324, 18325, 
18326, 18327, 18328), class = "Date"), x = c(23, 33, 48, 54, 
55, 49, 46, 38, 27, 33, 26, 47, 26, 29, 28, 73, 43, 40, 47, 38, 
57, 39, 45, 39, 56, 44, 54, 50, 49, 35, 70, 58, 51, 38, 1, 42, 
24, 15, 13, 22, 5, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 17, 19, 2, 9, 10, 4, 15, 
17, 2, 0, 1, 40, 41, 46, 59, 67, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), y = c(1, 
1, 2, 0, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 6, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 
1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 7, 0, 4, 2, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(605L, 606L, 607L, 608L, 609L, 
610L, 611L, 612L, 613L, 614L, 615L, 616L, 617L, 618L, 619L, 620L, 
621L, 622L, 623L, 624L, 625L, 626L, 627L, 628L, 629L, 630L, 631L, 
632L, 633L, 634L, 635L, 636L, 637L, 638L, 639L, 640L, 641L, 642L, 
643L, 644L, 645L, 646L, 647L, 648L, 649L, 650L, 651L, 854L, 855L, 
1091L, 1092L, 1093L, 1094L, 1095L, 1096L, 1202L, 1203L, 1204L, 
1220L, 1221L, 1222L, 1223L, 1224L, 1327L, 1328L, 1329L, 1330L, 
1331L, 1332L, 1333L), class = "data.frame")
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `position_dodge` but do not specify how to dodge the bars. You can do this by passing a grouping variable to aes. In this case, you also need to explicitely define the group.

I'd bring the data in a more ggplot like shape.

```r
library(tidyverse)

DF_long <- DF %>% mutate(y = y*10) %>%pivot_longer(names_to = "y_new", values_to = "val", x:y)

ggplot(DF_long, aes(x=date)) +
  geom_bar( aes(y = val, fill = y_new, group = y_new),
            stat="identity", position=position_dodge(),
            color="black", alpha=.6)  +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "x",sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*0.1, name="y"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks dear @Tjebo I will accept your answer, I only have one little issue, is there any way to adjust and define the limits in second y axis? I would like to display that scale from 0 to 10. Kind regards.